Google search API hanging indefinitely
I am writing a bit of code to give a local LLM that I am running the ability to do a google search, but for some reason the Google search API keeps having issues, and on some queries it just hangs indefinitely.
Here is an example of one:
import requests, html2text
from googlesearch import search

urls = []
query = "good restaurants near me"
for url in search(query, num_results=3, lang='en', timeout=5):
    urls.append(url)

print(html2text.html2text(requests.get(urls[0]).text))

This is the code I am running, I know it knows my location, and this is a valid search because when I set num results to 1, it works fine, but 2 or 3 and it runs forever.
I'm open to using a different library because I am kind of frustrated with this one, the fact that it completely ignores the timeout parameter is a huge oversight on their end. so if anyone has any recommendations, I'm all ears.
Code hangs indefinitely for num_results=2 or 3, runs fine for 1. Happens all the time for other searches.

Have you looked at the actual code that's blocking? Run your example in a debugger and step through, to find out where and why it blocks. Also keep in mind it could be the remote not responding. For a question here, you lack a [mcve], but apart from that, consider checking the library's bug tracker and perhaps filing a bug yourself.
